# How to use Helm template with existing Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

I am doing the migration of our application from docker compose to Kubernetes.
I chose the Helm charts as the instrument.
So now I have a question and have not found the answere anywhere.

Previously in docker compose we used next syntax for linking the Dockerfile in compose file:

```
name-of-service:
  build:
    - dockerfile: /path/to/dockerfile
```

Is there any way to do the same in helm chart? For example, I have next "values.yaml" file structure:

```
apps:
  app1:
    ...
  app2: 
    ...
```

Where can I add the link to Dockerfile? Thanks in advance!

I tried to find the way how to do the link to Dockerfile and did not find it anywhere.
I expect to paste the path to the Dockerfiles of each "app" in my values.yaml so they can be accessable.

Answer (score 3):

Neither Kubernetes nor Helm can build images.  You need to build an image separately (maybe in a CI pipeline), push it to some registry (use a unique tag per build), and reference that registry in your Pod spec's `image:` line.  In a Helm context you can use Helm values to inject the unique image tag, but you can't have Helm build the image itself.

Comment: Images can be built in Kubernetes. E.g. https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko